# why $3x<21 \implies x <7$

Tags: inequality

Lets say $ x= 6$

$6<21 =$ checks out

$x<21 = $ checks out because $ x$ is 6

$3x<21 = 3$ times 6 is 18, which is smaller than 21, checks out

It seems weird to me to divide by 3 and get rid of the coefficient and divide 21 also by three.

If we wrote the same inequality as above but like this, since $x $ is 6:

$3\times 6 <21 \implies 18<21$
why would we divide?
21 should be static, no?

Clarification: I'm trying to fix my intuition, because when I try to think of it in real terms, in example if someone told me that I had to pick up an object that was 21 meters away from me(that is physical distance) it seems weird to me that by mathematical manipulations that distance would change to 7, it wouldn't make physical space, I'm definitely doing something wrong here but not sure what or how.

Update: my confusion has ended, thanks for the replies.

Comment: Among the many properties of the less than relation, `<`, include that if $a<b$ then $a+c<b+c$ and that if $0<c$ and $a<b$ then $a\times c<b\times c$.  In your specific scenario, we have $a=3x, b=21$ and $c=\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: As for possible reasons why your post is being downvoted., one possibility might be "lack of research effort."  Any source that rigorously defines the less than relation would include what I just wrote in my comment above which should have immediately answered your question.

Comment: By dividing $21$ by three, you get an answer that restricts $x$ to a smaller interval: $x<7$. The purpose is to try to get $x$ as close to its real value rather than just saying $3x<21$. Both statements are true, but by saying $x<7$, $x$ is much closer to it's value of $6$ and it is a much simpler form

Comment: But can you do that in real life? I mean, if you have to pick up an object at 21 meters and so far you have walked an x amount 3 times, and you measure the x and it is 6 and you multiply by 3 and you find out that you have walked 18 meters.
In real life you don't magically divide x by three and magically by division change the actual distance of the object you're trying to pick up from 21 meters to 7, that is my confusion

Comment: Also, mathjax is almost a requirement to get positive responses (as well as providing your attempts and understanding). Mathjax would make this question  *much* easier to understand than "why 3x<21 --> x<7". It would be to your benefit to write: "Why do we reduce $3x<21$ to $x<7$"

Comment: It's a little bit unclear to me what "21 should be static" means. Let's try to clarify your point of confusion: (i) Do you doubt that, if $x<7$, then $3x<21$? (ii) Do you doubt that, if $3x<21$, then $x<7$? (iii) If you doubt either, do you think you have a counterexample in mind? Or (iv) are you asking why we would *want* to go from $3x<21$ to $x<7$ (not why we *can*)?

Comment: "*But can you do that in real life?...21 meters...an amount of x three times...*"  How about this... what if the amount was instead $21$ feet (*using the frustrating measurement system of USA*)... we could choose instead of talking about feet to instead talk about yards (*remembering a yard is three feet*).  We didn't "magically change anything" we just changed what words we were using to describe the scenario.

Comment: @JMoravitz but if this was a real "word problem" in real life, and you had an item at 21 feet, would you use the same tactic to reduce 21 feet into 7 feet? It wouldn't make physical sense or perhaps I'm misunderstanding something deeply

Comment: It sounds like a lack of imagination on your part, like you think each conclusion that can be drawn from algebraic manipulations must have some real world scenario that perfectly describes it.  Although real world scenarios can be helpful to build intuition, they are by no means necessary to trust or understand mathematical properties, definitions, or theorems.

Comment: As for a real world scenario that might be useful for this...  "Publicboi has 21 dollars.  He wants to buy three books that all cost the same and is told that he can indeed afford it with the money he has.  Given this information alone, If he changes his mind and wants to buy only a single book what is the smallest amount of money he needs to be guaranteed to able to afford it?"

Comment: You can see : [Inequalities : properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_(mathematics)#Properties).

Comment: @JMoravitz but you wouldn't say that suddenly you have 7 dollars just because you can afford the three books, right?

Comment: See [Inequality : multiplication and division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_(mathematics)#Multiplication_and_division) : "For any real numbers, a, b and non-zero c: If c is positive, then multiplying or dividing by c does not change the inequality." Thus, apply it with $2x$ as $a$ and $21$ as $b$ and $3$ (which is positive) as $c$.

Comment: No, I wouldn't say that "*i suddenly have 7 dollars just because I can afford the three books*" but I would say that "*In the event that I wanted to purchase only one book instead, I would need to budget at most 7 dollars to be sure that I could afford it, allowing me to use my remaining 14 dollars elsewhere.*"

Comment: You seem to be worried about "where the remaining 14 dollars" or "where the remaining 14 meters" went... it didn't go anywhere.  The number on the right of the inequality does *not* represent how many dollars or how many meters are present... but only represents an upper bound on the size of $x$.

Comment: Ok Noah's answer did it for me, I understood what was my confusion

Comment: I just want to go on record as disagreeing with the negative reception of this question. The question is poorly articulated, but the nature of such confusions is precisely that they are hard to articulate! I think this is a perfectly reasonable question for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: based on the OP's comments below their question, I suspect part of the confusion here is *semantic*, so let me address that separately.

Let's take the example they mention:

> you have to pick up an object at 21 meters and so far you have walked an x amount 3 times, and you measure the x and it is 6 and you multiply by 3 and you find out that you have walked 18 meters

We have two quantities - besides $x$ - that we care about:

- $w$, the distance walked so far *(this happens to be $18$, since $w=3x$ and $x=6$)*; and
- $D$, the total distance to the object *(this happens to be $21$)*.

Now here I think is the crux: when you see "$3x<21$" you may think "Aha, this is just saying that the distance walked so far is less than the total distance." However, when you *then* see "$x<7$" it may look like we've somehow "shrunk the distance."

That's **not** what's happened, however! Rather, you should think of the new equation as saying $$\mbox{One third of the distance travelled so far is less than one third of the total distance.}$$ Note that $x$ is indeed one third of the distance travelled so far, and $7$ is indeed one third of the total distance. We haven't changed any aspect of the situation we're considering.

It might help to consider the following thought process:

- We know we walked some distance $x$ three times, and still haven't reached our target which is $21$ feet away.
- This tells us that $3x<21$.
- From this, what can we conclude about $x$?

For example, we know that $x$ **can't** be $9$ - if we'd travelled $9$ feet three times, we'd have already reached (and passed) our target since $3\cdot 9>21$.

If you think about this for a bit, hopefully it will become clear that what you can conclude is exactly "$x<7$" - that is, without measuring it I don't know exactly what distance it is that we've travelled three times, but I know it's less than $7$ feet.

---

The simplest response is: *You can't change one part of an expression without changing the other.* For example:

- $9<21$ is certainly true.
- $\color{red}{3}\cdot 9<21$, however, is certainly *false*
- However, $\color{red}{3}\cdot 9<\color{red}{3}\cdot 21$ is once again *true* (it's just saying $27<63$).

If you play around with a bunch of example values of $x$, you should quickly notice that whenever you choose an $x$ which is $<7$ it so happens that $3x$ is $<21$; and similarly whenever you choose an $x$ such that $3x<21$, it so happens that $x<7$.

I think you might have confused yourself by looking at $x=6$, which has the annoying property that both $x<21$ and $3x<21$ happen to be true; for **general** $x$, just knowing that $x<21$ doesn't tell us that $3x<21$.

---

It might be easier to think about *equations*, rather than *inequalities*, to begin with: if I know that $2x=5$, then surely I can conclude that $x={5\over 2}$.

The same thing is happening here: inequalities are preserved when I multiply both sides by a positive number, so:

- I can get from $3x<21$ to $x<7$ by multiplying each side of the former by ${1\over 3}$ (which is positive).
- I can get from $x<7$ to $3x<21$ by multiplying each side of the former by $3$ (which is positive).

Note that we do have to be careful here: unlike equations, inequalities are **not** always preserved by doing the same thing to both sides! For example, $1<2$ is true but $-1<-2$ is false, so multiplying both sides of an inequality by a *negative* number is problematic.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the downvote?

Comment: not me, I'm still reading the replies

Comment: @publicboiboipublic I've edited to add a bit about the semantics of algebraic reasoning in this case, which might help.

Comment: >One third of the distance travelled so far is less than one third of the total distance.
This clicked with me instantly, yeah, I obviously can solve infinite of those inequalities mechanically but I didn't have the intuition to what was happening.
Another poster said that it didn't map on the physical world but you explained it perfectly how it would work in real life.
Great.

Comment: @publicboiboipublic Glad I could help!